# Vertx with PgClient giving error 'Could not initialize class' in native image

Tags: java, vert.x, graalvm-native-image

I've a vertx program with Pgclient usage, and it is working fine. now when I'm build native image it was successful. When I ran my native image build it is giving me error like that:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.DataTypeCodec

I've vertx project using by common code repository for common methods like pg client initialization and RMQ initialization.
my main project is db-writer which is using backend-common:

in db-writer pom.xml I've added:

backend-common (dependency)

in my backend-common pom.xml I've:

io.vertx
vertx-pg-client (dependency)

when I'm running my project without native image it is running fine.

GraalVM and environment:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

native-image properties

```
Args=\
--no-fallback \
--enable-http \
--enable-https \
--allow-incomplete-classpath \
--enable-all-security-services \
-H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https \
-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=${.}/reflect-config.json \
-H:ResourceConfigurationResources=${.}/resource-config.json \
-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
--report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime \
--initialize-at-build-time=\
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,\
org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger,\
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder,\
org.slf4j.MDC,\
ch.qos.logback \
--initialize-at-run-time=\
io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgCodec,\
io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.DataTypeCodec,\
io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLogger,\
io.netty.util.AbstractReferenceCounted,\
io.netty.channel.epoll,\
io.netty.handler.ssl,\
io.netty.channel.unix,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateCompressionAlgo,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifier,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLPrivateKeyMethod,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateCompressionAlgo,\
io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifier
```

Error stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.DataTypeCodec
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.writeBind(PgEncoder.java:427)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.ExtendedQueryCommandCodec.encode(ExtendedQueryCommandCodec.java:52)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.write(PgEncoder.java:102)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.write(PgEncoder.java:133)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:792)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:702)
at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.lambda$prepareCommand$4(SocketConnectionBase.java:264)
at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.command.CommandResponse.fire(CommandResponse.java:46)
at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.handleMessage(SocketConnectionBase.java:287)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.PgSocketConnection.handleMessage(PgSocketConnection.java:97)
at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.lambda$init$0(SocketConnectionBase.java:100)
at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:55)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.emit(ContextBase.java:239)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:394)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:157)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.lambda$write$0(PgEncoder.java:98)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgCommandCodec.handleReadyForQuery(PgCommandCodec.java:139)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PrepareStatementCommandCodec.handleReadyForQuery(PrepareStatementCommandCodec.java:96)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.decodeReadyForQuery(PgDecoder.java:237)
at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.channelRead(PgDecoder.java:96)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
```